# Server OS usage index

Tags: performance

Is there any server OS usage index (like [tiobe index](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html) for programming languages)?
I haven't found anything better than google trends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe have a look at http://distrowatch.com/ seems to be along the lines of what your after

Answer (score 1):

[Netcraft](http://news.netcraft.com/) tracks web server/OS marketshare.

Some caveats:

- It's fairly easy to "trick" Netcraft with headers.
- Netcraft can only scrape pages that are publicly available. This means it misses databases, business logic, and intranet sites.
- It also means that their stats may be skewed by load balancers.
- And they're web biased, so they're not tracking MX servers, ssh servers, etc.